# Interpreting estimates of a Gamma distribution

Tags: matlab, maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution

I have 399 claim amount of data, i want to fit them using a Gamma distribution. I have done so in Matlab software However i am getting this as my result:

> > [phat,pci] = gamfit(data)

phat =

1.0e+004 *

```
0.0001    2.8951
```

why i am getting the 1.0e+004*? Thanks

Comment: Although I am happy that you got an answer, this kind of question really doesn't fit here as it pivots on a particular software implementation. Please see the help center for advice on software-related questions.

Answer (score 5):

This means that the first component of vector phat is `0.0001*10^4 = 1` and the other is `2.8951*10^4 = 28951`

Comment: With only one significant figure visible, unless the first parameter has been set to exactly 1, *it might be anything between 0.5 and 1.5*. Yikes. Second, the question has only been up 11 hours -- while user40494's positive response suggests that they should upvote your answer (and for all I know they already have), not enough time has passed for you to assume yet that yours will necessarily be the *best* answer (one that should be accepted). They'd be quite within their rights to wait for a better one. If they've made a habit of not accepting answers, and time has passed, ... (ctd)